# Why is mongoDB taking up so much RAM space?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, query-optimization, out-of-memory, pymongo

I've managed to write a simple indexer script for mongoDB using pymongo. But I've no idea why would indexing, adding documents and querying would take up 96GB of the RAM on my server.

**Is it because my query isn't optimized? How could i optimize my query instead of** `database.find_one({"eng":src})`

**How else could i optimize my indexer script?**

So my inputs are as such (the actual data inputs have **2 million+ lines** of varying length of sentence):

**#srcfile**

```
You will be aware from the press and television that there have been a number of bomb explosions and killings in Sri Lanka.
One of the people assassinated very recently in Sri Lanka was Mr Kumar Ponnambalam, who had visited the European Parliament just a few months ago.
Would it be appropriate for you, Madam President, to write a letter to the Sri Lankan President expressing Parliament's regret at his and the other violent deaths in Sri Lanka and urging her to do everything she possibly can to seek a peaceful reconciliation to a very difficult situation?
Yes, Mr Evans, I feel an initiative of the type you have just suggested would be entirely appropriate.
If the House agrees, I shall do as Mr Evans has suggested.
```

**#trgfile**

```
Wie Sie sicher aus der Presse und dem Fernsehen wissen, gab es in Sri Lanka mehrere Bombenexplosionen mit zahlreichen Toten.
Zu den Attentatsopfern, die es in jüngster Zeit in Sri Lanka zu beklagen gab, zählt auch Herr Kumar Ponnambalam, der dem Europäischen Parlament erst vor wenigen Monaten einen Besuch abgestattet hatte.
Wäre es angemessen, wenn Sie, Frau Präsidentin, der Präsidentin von Sri Lanka in einem Schreiben das Bedauern des Parlaments zum gewaltsamen Tod von Herrn Ponnambalam und anderen Bürgern von Sri Lanka übermitteln und sie auffordern würden, alles in ihrem Kräften stehende zu tun, um nach einer friedlichen Lösung dieser sehr schwierigen Situation zu suchen?
Ja, Herr Evans, ich denke, daß eine derartige Initiative durchaus angebracht ist.
Wenn das Haus damit einverstanden ist, werde ich dem Vorschlag von Herrn Evans folgen.
```

An example doc looks like this

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("50f5fe8916174763f6217994"), 
    "deu" : "Wie Sie sicher aus der Presse und dem Fernsehen wissen, gab es in Sri 
             Lanka mehrere Bombenexplosionen mit zahlreichen Toten.\n", 
    "uid" : 13, 
    "eng" : "You will be aware from the press and television that there have been a 
             number of bomb explosions and killings in Sri Lanka." 
}
```

**My code**:

```py
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import codecs, glob, os
from pymongo import MongoClient
from itertools import izip
from bson.code import Code

import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

# Gets first instance of matching key given a value and a dictionary.    
def getKey(dic, value):
  return [k for k,v in dic.items() if v == value]

def langiso (lang, isochar=3):
  languages = {"en":"eng",
               "da":"dan","de":"deu",
               "es":"spa",
               "fi":"fin","fr":"fre",
               "it":"ita",
               "nl":"nld",
               "zh":"mcn"}
  if len(lang) == 2 or isochar==3:
    return languages[lang]
  if len(lang) == 3 or isochar==2:
    return getKey(lang)

def txtPairs (bitextDir):
  txtpairs = {}
  for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(bitextDir, '*')):
    #print infile
    k = infile[-8:-3]; lang = infile[-2:]
    try:
      txtpairs[k] = (txtpairs[k],infile) if lang == "en" else (infile,txtpairs[k]) 
    except:
      txtpairs[k] = infile
  for i in txtpairs:
    if len(txtpairs[i]) != 2:
      del txtpairs[i]
  return txtpairs

def indexEuroparl(sfile, tfile, database):   
  trglang = langiso(tfile[-2:]) #; srclang = langiso(sfile[-2:]) 

  maxdoc = database.find().sort("uid",-1).limit(1)
  uid = 1 if maxdoc.count() == 0 else maxdoc[0]

  counter = 0
  for src, trg in izip(codecs.open(sfile,"r","utf8"), \
                       codecs.open(tfile,"r","utf8")):
    quid = database.find_one({"eng":src})
    # If sentence already exist in db
    if quid != None:
      if database.find({trglang: {"$exists": True}}):
        print "Sentence uniqID",quid["uid"],"already exist."
        continue
      else:
        print "Reindexing uniqID",quid["uid"],"..."
        database.update({"uid":quid["uid"]}, {"$push":{trglang:trg}})
    else:
      print "Indexing uniqID",uid,"..."
      doc = {"uid":uid,"eng":src,trglang:trg}
      database.insert(doc)
      uid+=1
    if counter == 1000:
      for i in database.find():
        print i
      counter = 0
    counter+=1

connection = MongoClient()
db = connection["europarl"]
v7 = db["v7"]

srcfile = "eng-deu.en"; trgfile = "eng-deu.de"
indexEuroparl(srcfile,trgfile,v7)

# After indexing the english-german pair, i'll perform the same indexing on other language pairs
srcfile = "eng-spa.en"; trgfile = "eng-spa.es"
indexEuroparl(srcfile,trgfile,v7)
```

Comment: To save us from having to attempt to understand you code can you show us an example doc?

Comment: So you are querying by the thing you need to get out? The translation? Correct my if I am wrong but to get the query you are looking for you must already know that which you wish to pull out, which means: why is the query being performed?

Comment: put `getIndexes` output and `explain()` of the query

Comment: The single biggest problem is the size of the field, I am surprised MongoDB will even index it, it must be just shy of 1024 bytes. I am unsure if there is any easy way to store or index such a field, no matter which way you slice that index it is gonna be big and cumbersome to query

Comment: @Sammaye isn't that what the hu"mongo"us  db suppose to do?

So i need to query whether the sentences was already indexed before. loop through a new set of textpairs, i can add an additional row for a column for a different translation

Comment: @2er0 Technically your index is possible but your RAM usage sounds about right for it (considering how many sentences and translations you need to index), MongoDB cannot defy the laws of computation, it ain't that magical. Hmm what if you hashed the sentence to, say, md5? That could be easier to query though I am unsure.

Comment: Okay i'm doing a small experiment where i added a line `v7.ensure_index([("eng",1),("unique",True)])`. Possibly that should shorten the process of querying right? Since it's no longer doing serial search but searching through a hashed index.

Comment: Possibly, worth a test on that front

Comment: I've reran the script with the additional `ensure_index()` but i dont understand why is mongodb still storing information into the RAM. It's slowly eating up the RAM. 130,000 sentences with 2.4GB used

Comment: The details are a little hazy but I would say it is fundamental to how MongoDB runs due the OS LRU. MongoDB will try to use as much memory as the OS will let it loading everything you need (your working set) into RAM from virtual memory including indexes and documents, though 2.4gb of ram is a lot less than 96gb. It shoudl be noted that the LRU will not page out items until it is full so it slowly increasing could just mean that you are now able to cache more into memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several rounds of code profiling, I've found where the RAM was leaking to.

Firstly, if i want to query the `"eng"` field often, i should create an index for that field by doing this:

```
v7.ensure_index([("eng",1),("unique",True)])
```

That resolves the time taken for serial searches across the unindexed `"eng"` field.

Second, the bleeding RAM problem is due to this costly function call:

```
doc = {"uid":uid,"eng":src,trglang:trg}
if counter == 1000:
  for i in database.find():
    print i
  counter = 0
counter+=1
```

What MongoDb does is that it stores the results into the RAM as `@Sammaye` had noticed. And each time i call the database.find(), it keeps in the RAM a whole set of docs i've added to the collection. That's how i burn out 96GB of RAMs. The above snippet needs to be changed to:

```
doc = {"uid":uid,"eng":src,trglang:trg}
if counter == 1000:
  print doc
counter+=1
```

By eliminating the database.find() and creating the index for `"eng"` field, I'm only using up to 25GB and I've completed the index for 2 million sentences in less than 1 hour.